# How to aggregate multiple columns - Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have this df:

```
ID         Date  XXX  123_Var  456_Var  789_Var  123_P  456_P  789_P
 A  07/16/2019     1      987      551      313     22     12     94
 A  07/16/2019     9      135      748      403     92     40     41
 A  07/18/2019     8      376      938      825     14     69     96
 A  07/18/2019     5      259      176      674     52     75     72
 B   07/16/2019    9      690      304      948     56     14     78
 B   07/16/2019    8      819      185      699     33     81     83
 B   07/18/2019    1      580      210      847     51     64     87
```

I want to group the df by `ID` and `Date`, aggregate the `XXX` column by the maximum value, and aggregate `123_Var`, `456_Var`, `789_Var` columns by the minimum value.

*** Note: The df contains many of these columns. The shape is: `{some int}_Var`.**

This is the current code I've started to write:

```
df = (df.groupby(['ID','Date'], as_index=False)
        .agg({'XXX':'max', list(df.filter(regex='_Var')): 'min'}))
```

Expected result:

```
ID         Date  XXX  123_Var  456_Var  789_Var
 A  07/16/2019     9      135      551      313
 A  07/18/2019     8      259      176      674
 B   07/16/2019    9      690      185      699
 B   07/18/2019    1      580      210      847
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create dictionary dynamic with `dict.fromkeys` and then [merge  it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression) with `{'XXX':'max'}` dict and pass to [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
d = dict.fromkeys(df.filter(regex='_Var').columns, 'min')
df = df.groupby(['ID','Date'], as_index=False).agg({**{'XXX':'max'}, **d})
print (df)
  ID        Date  XXX  123_Var  456_Var  789_Var
0  A  07/16/2019    9      135      551      313
1  A  07/18/2019    8      259      176      674
2  B  07/16/2019    9      690      185      699
3  B  07/18/2019    1      580      210      847
```